# sqlServer prob: When i want to enter data in a table in c#, the data are not registered in it. No exception thrown

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I can repeat my prob from many project so I'm doing something wrong. I think it's my `connectionstring` but I'm not sure. My database was created in `vistual studio 2013`. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here my connectionString:

```
`Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConnectLocalData\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30`
```

And the code:

```
SqlConnection Yop = new (SqlConnection(customersTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString);
            Yop.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Phone) Values (@CustomerID,@CompanyName, @ContactName, @Phone)", Yop);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", textBox1.Text);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", textBox2.Text);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", textBox3.Text);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", textBox4.Text);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Yop.Close();
```

Comment: Is an exception thrown?  What does your connection string look like?  (Blank out any password it may contain).

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConnectLocalData\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Comment: Your connection string looks like SQL Server's, but the tag and the caption is "mysql"... So may be you are inserting into LocalDB (SQL Server), but checking against completely different MySQL-server?

Comment: oops sorry it's a sql server

Comment: So, in Visual Studio in the server explorer, if you expand the SQLServer node, do you have more than one server listed there?

Comment: no I only have one server!

Comment: This question has been asked over and over again. First with SQL Server Compact, now with LocalDB. Do a search here on SO. With SQL Server Compact, the problem was usually that the OP did not look at the same DB file that is attached to the server & modified. So the INSERT actually succeeds, but in another DB than the one you're checking. Not sure if it's different with LocalDB.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Try` and  `Catch` to figure out The [Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/0yd65esw.aspx):

> Before that,be confirmed, are you really passing the Correct `DataType`
>   to `Query`?

```
Try
{
SqlConnection Yop = new (SqlConnection(customersTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString);
            Yop.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Phone) Values (@CustomerID,@CompanyName, @ContactName, @Phone)", Yop);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", textBox1.Text);

  //if CustomerID is not a string type(i.e Integer) in Table then you need to convert value of textBox1.Text ,Like 
//sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));

            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", textBox2.Text);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", textBox3.Text);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", textBox4.Text);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Yop.Close();
}
Catch(Exception e1)
{
Response.Write(e1.Messege);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `CustomerID` in the table `autoincrement`? If yes you must not add this parameter in your query.

You may need to cast some parameters to the same type as your database (`customerId` and `phone` in `Int`?)

like this

```
addwithvalue("phone", Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text));
```

You may put your code in a `try` and catch exception to known what is the problem

Comment: My customerID is not autoincrement, cast are not the prob i tried with and without same prob and I have no exception throw  so i can't catch it

Comment: Can you give us more details one your mysql table structure?